# Как элементы массива поместить в дивы в виде текста?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть массив и его элементы нужно поместить в дивы в виде текста. Я перебираю массив с указанием создавать для каждого элемента див и соответственно каждый индекс массива вложить как текст, но не получается.

```
let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
           
/* <--------START--------> */
let div
    
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `<p>${days [i]}</p>`;
```

Comment: Просто добавьте затем, созданный вами, див куда-то, например, в конце боди: `document.body.append(div)`. Пока он не добавлен, он существует лишь "в уме".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
           
/* <--------START--------> */
let element = document.body;
    
for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `<p>${days [i]}</p>`;
  element.append( div );
}
```

`element` — другой элемент, внутрь которого будут помещёны Ваши div(-ы)